# Ã© instead of "é", definitely don't know why

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8

I have a website displaying **Ã© characters instead of "é".**

I found this thread [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/how-to-support-utf-8-completely-in-a-web-application?noredirect=1&lq=1) which is great but did not help me. I can't see why.

Data is been pulled from a Mysql database. SHOW VARIABLES gives :

```
character_set_client : utf8
character_set_connection : utf8
character_set_database : utf8
character_set_filesystem : binary
character_set_results : utf8
character_set_server : utf8
character_set_system : utf8
character_sets_dir : /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
collation_connection : utf8_unicode_ci
collation_database : utf8_general_ci
collation_server : utf8_general_ci
```

My php Header + PDO::connexion code is the following, setting utf-8 as charset :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
         <?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
         <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
         $db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=host.mysql.db;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'user', '');
         $db->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Then my PDO:query code is the following, I don't specify charset but I don't see why / how to do it :

```
$query="SELECT * FROM db where rank = 1 limit 30";
$req = $db->query($query) or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));
$req->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data1 = array();
$data1 = $req->fetchAll();
```

Finally I print data, giving Ã© characters.

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i):
    $title = utf8_encode($data1[$i]['title']);
    echo mb_check_encoding($title, "UTF-8"); // prints 1 (True)
    echo $title; // prints Ã©
```

Note : If I use "utf8_decode()" on "data" instead of "utf8_encode()", I get � characters.

I am using Notepad++ and my files are encoded "UTF8 without BOM".

**HINT : It works on localhost database. I put it online (OVH) and now I have these Ã© characters**.

On this local database, SHOW VARIABLES gives :

```
character_set_client : utf8mb4
character_set_connection : utf8mb4
character_set_database : latin1
character_set_filesystem : binary
character_set_results : utf8mb4
character_set_server : latin1
character_set_system : utf8
character_sets_dir : c:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.11\share\charsets\
check_proxy_users :OFF
collation_connection : utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_database : latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server : latin1_swedish_ci
```

Comment: 1. Why do you need the `utf8_encode` there? 2. What is the structure of your table?

Comment: Wow. I removed the superfluous utf8_encode and it works... ! Put it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You data should already be encoded in `UTF-8` so you shouldn't have the `utf8_encode` function there.

The function [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) encodes an `ISO-8859-1` string to `UTF-8`, and this is not what you need.

Just remove this function and it should work.

Comment: This led me to a solution. Thanks.